# Cannot access local server with IP address while localhost and 127.0.0.1 can

Tags: 16.04, firewall, localhost, hosts

I am trying to let other computers to access my local server but I tried myself locally that **I cannot access it locally even myself**.

Several things you should know:

#### My target

Visit my server via http://172.26.141.106:5201/

#### What I can do now

I can access my server via these two ways:

- http://localhost:5201
- http://127.0.0.1:5201

#### IP configuration

Result of `ifconfig | grep inet`

```
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet addr:172.26.141.106  Bcast:172.26.141.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::f767:cd56:9641:d3a9/64 Scope:Link
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

#### Hosts

Output of `cat /etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1   hearen.pc
127.0.0.1   hearen-OptiPlex-7050
127.0.0.1   staging
127.0.0.1   arthas
172.26.141.106  localhost hearen.pc
```

#### Firewall

```
$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Is there some way that I missed out? All I want is to let others access my server via http://172.26.141.106:5201/

Any help will be appreciated :)

#### Updated 2019-01-10

With the help of @Ed King, I check the *ports* via `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN  | grep 5201` and only `127.0.0.1` was listenned on.

Problem solved after I configured my Angular server to listen on `0.0.0.0` .

Comment: In the /etc/hosts file above localhost points to 2 different IP addresses, is this allowed? Will it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check that your server is listening:

```
sudo lsof -n | grep TCP | grep LISTEN
```

You can also check the route using nc.  Start nc on the server listening on an unused port and then connect from another machine -- this will verify iptables and routes are correct.

My guess is that you're listening on the localhost only.

Comment: Thank you, you are leading the right direction. It is and now I configure it to listen on `0.0.0.0`. Problem solved. Thanks for the help. I will mark your answer after minutes when I am allowed.

Comment: Thanks for making me think in the correct direction.

If you landed here due to google firebase echosystem, please refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260877/access-firebase-emulator-from-local-network

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue with following ways:

1. I run the command

   ```
   sudo ufw status
   ```

   And I found that the port 80 (in my case) was not in the list.
2. Then I run the command

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 80
   ```

   This fixed the issue.

Comment: This will work if ufw was his problem -- in his question he disabled ufw and still could not connect.